# Protect shared memory between distinct processes

Tags: multiprocessing, shared-memory, python-3.8

Since python 3.8, it is possible to share memory between distinct processes (without any parent-child relationship) with the `multiprocessing.shared_memory` module. However, it doesn't seem to provide any synchronisation primitives. So how do you prevent data corruption with concurrent updates to the shared data?

I suppose the locks that the `multiprocessing` module provides will work for processes that are spawned by the main process, not for distinct processes.

Comment: how are you spawning the processes, if not from the main process?

Comment: You can use a named lock which is supported by both [Windows](https://github.com/benhoyt/namedmutex) and [Posix](https://pypi.org/project/posix-ipc/) based systems, though unfortunately not by python standard library to my knowledge.